# ListAdapter On Xamarin for Android

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin

I create `ListView` using `ListAdapter` on Android Xamarin. I am using it on Activity which extend ListActivity

This is my code

```
ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (
    this, 
    Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, 
    new string[] { "tes1", "tes2", "tes3" }
);
```

When I put that in `Oncreate()` it shown. But I do need that `ListAdapter` to bind some data when some event (says download completed event) so I put it in a method which I call after download data completed but why `ListAdapter` can't be shown? My `ListView` become empty. I am using the same code as above.

this is my OnCreate method

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);

            _DataTopStories = new TopStoriesViewModel();
            _DataService = new DataService();


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListTopStoriesLayout);

            _DataService.GetTopStories();
            _DataService.DownloadCompleted += _DataService_DownloadCompleted;
```

this is Download Event Completed

```
void _DataService_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var raw = ((DownloadEventArgs)e).ResultDownload;
            if(raw!=null)
            {
                _DataTopStories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopStoriesViewModel>(raw);
                CreateList();
                Log.Info("ds", "download completed");
            }
        }
```

this is `CreateList()` method

```
private void CreateList()
        {
            Log.Info("ds", "list");
            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Application.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, new string[] { "tes4", "tes52", "tes6" });
            Log.Info("ds", "set adapter");

        }
```

And in Android logcat "set adapter" will not shown. It looks stopped on ListAdapter.

Comment: if I read it true in xamarin there is no need to set adapter. Because I am just using that in OnCreate() and it works

Comment: you are right :) then Application.Context is wrong .. you need to use Activity context ...

Comment: I am already change Application.Context to this but still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Found my solution. To update ListAdapter I need to run it on UI Thread so this is my new Download Completed Event

```
void _DataService_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var raw = ((DownloadEventArgs)e).ResultDownload;
            if(raw!=null)
            {
                _DataTopStories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopStoriesViewModel>(raw);
                RunOnUiThread(() => CreateList());
                //CreateList();
                Log.Info("ds", "download completed");
            }
        }
```